# Low Events: wrong date displayed

Tags: date, low-events

I have a site with the following url:

```
domain.com/theater/events/2016-01-13
```

On said page I have this tag:

```
{exp:low_events:entries channel="events" date="{segment_3}" limit="1"}
   <option>{title}/ {event:start_date}</option>
{/exp:low_events:entries}
```

Now `{event:start_date}` always displays `2015-12-01` no matter what happens in the `url_segment`.

Why is that?

If I replace `{event:start_date}` with `{segment_3}` It shows the right date but then I'can't reformat the date. Anyone had this problem before?

--

Edit:

I further examined the problem. If I remove `limit="1"` then there are two entries displayed. One is the correct date and one is always the `2015-12-01`. Ho can I just grab the date which matches the `url_segment`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL has the date in `{segment_2}` and you're using `date="{segment_3}"`.

Also, if the entry/event spans multiple days, the start_date will display the event's start date, not the current date given.

**Edit:** Note that using `date="..."` is specifically designed to display events according to a date range. Using `date="2016-01-13"` will display all events that are *active* on January 13th 2015. This includes events that start that day, that end that day and that are active during that day (start before and end after).

If you're after displaying a *single* entry/event, you can also just use the channel:entries tag like you would with any old single entry, and use the entry's url_title to determine which entry/event you want to show.

**Edit 2:** After [some investigation](https://getsatisfaction.com/low/topics/url-segment-displays-the-wrong-date#reply_16279812) it turned out there *were* events that span multiple days (years even). Correcting those entries solved the issue.

Comment: you are right. This was an error but it still displays a wrong date.

Comment: No date spans multiple days

Comment: I reckon the other entry spans multiple dates. If not, try and edit that entry and re-save.

Comment: The entry does not span multiple dates. I re-saved the entry. It just displays `2015-12-01`

Comment: Can you open a [GetSat thread](https://getsatisfaction.com/low) to further debug this? Include your EE, LE and PHP versions, as well as Template Debugger output for all Low Events lines.